# Error reading data from Firestore by FutureBuilder method

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to output the data of one user, but an error crashes: does not accept the getDocId function in Futurebuilders, where do I need to fix the code?

```
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  List<String> docIds = [];
  Future getDocId() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get().then(
        (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
          docIds.add(document.reference.id);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
              future: getDocId(), // here
              builder: ((context, snapshot) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: docIds.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: GetUser(documentId: docIds[index]),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }),
            ),
```

Comment: How was it related to `C` tag. Do not **spam** tags. C tag removed

Comment: what error you are facing?

Comment: Actually the way of using FutureBuilder is wrong here. You should return data from your future function and use it in FutureBuilder body from the snapshot.data. 

Reference link :
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Vishal has it right, I think: you're missing `return docIds` at the end of your `getDocId` function. You also should not mix `await` and `then()`, but use one **or** the other.

So:

```
Future getDocId() async {
  var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get()
  snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
    docIds.add(document.reference.id);
  })
  return docIds
}
```

(typos are possible; if the code doesn't work as is, please look for those yourself before posting back)